# How to declare Get/Set methods without names on an object?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create a C# class that supports the following...

```
// Sets a string: sg(1,1) = "value";
// Gets a string: "value" = sg(1,1);
// sg.ExportToExcel(ClosedXML.Excel.Worksheet, row = 1, col = 1) // Write sg to Excel for worksheet X, starting at row or row/col

Example Usage:

StringGrid sg = new StringGrid();

// Row/Col addressable "cells"
sg(1,1) = "Eastern Cities";
sg(2,1) = "Boston";
sg(3,1) = "New York";
sg(4,1) = "Atlanta";
// Skipping second 'column' is intentional and needs to be rendered correctly by ExportToExcel() [in other words, use Arrays, not List<string>]
sg(1,3) = "Western Cities";
sg(2,3) = "Los Angeles";
sg(3,3) = "Seattle";

Console.WriteLine(sg(2,1));  // Outputs "Boston"

sg.ExportToExcel(ws,row: 10);
```

Yes, it is only a two-dimensional string grid using [string] arrays with an additional method [and it starts at 1,1, not 0,0].

First, I know how that I could create getValue/setValue methods.  That's the easy way out.  However, I realized that I'd like to make it "simpler" to use.  I realized that I have no idea how to declare/write this code to work with as per the "example" above.  Is it even possible?

Comment: Maybe a simple two dimensional string array is sufficient for you?

Comment: Have you looked into making an indexer for your class?

Comment: Yes, technically I could have used a simple two-dimensional string array [which I mentioned], but I wanted it to start at 1,1 and access the data like the sample.  More importantly, notice I didn't want to define the size in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create indexer for your class like this:

```
class StringGrid {
    // just a sample storage
    // might actually work if you only need to address whole rows
    // but not whole columns
    private readonly Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, string>> _values = new Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, string>>();
    // indexer 
    public string this[int x, int y]
    {
        get
        {
            // various checks omited
            return _values[x][y];
        }
        set
        {
            if (!_values.ContainsKey(x))
                _values.Add(x, new Dictionary<int, string>());
            _values[x][y] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Then change all "(" to "[" and ")" to "]" and it will work:

```
sg[1, 1] = "Eastern Cities";
sg[2, 1] = "Boston";
sg[3, 1] = "New York";
sg[4, 1] = "Atlanta";
// Skipping second 'column' is intentional and needs to be rendered correctly by ExportToExcel() [in other words, use Arrays, not List<string>]
sg[1, 3] = "Western Cities";
sg[2, 3] = "Los Angeles";
sg[3, 3] = "Seattle";

Console.WriteLine(sg[2, 1]);  // Outputs "Boston"
```

Comment: I'll play with this approach... I had tried a number of syntaxes with parentheses and couldn't get it to work.  I eventually found the .Net Array class (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array(v=vs.110).aspx) which I thought would work. It has a 2-d string CreateInstance method, but the Resize method only support 1-d [what?].

Comment: Both Evk and @Alex van Vliet offered basically the same solution.  Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1):

For your first two questions, you can use [indexers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/indexers/index). These allow to access a class just like you would with an array.

For example, this could be an implementation :

```
class Test
{
    private string[,] cells;

    public Test(int height, int width)
    {
        cells = new string[height, width];
    }

    // This is where it gets interesting : this will be called when you access your class, for example, like this :
    // Test t = new Test(5, 5);
    // t[2, 3] = "test"; => set will be called
    // or 
    // Console.WriteLine(t[2, 3]); => get will be called
    public string this[int y, int x]
    {
        get
        {
             return cells[y, x];
        }
        set
        {
           cells[y, x] = value; // Value is the part which is after the "="
        }
    }
}
```

You can easily adapt your code to your exact needs.
However, I don't think that there is a way to make this with parentheses.

About the excel part, I don't know how to manipulate excel files in C#, I strongly suggest you to make another topic as there is a "one question = one topic" approach.

PS : About the comment you put "in other words, use Arrays, not List". This is in the implementation side, it doesn't have anything to do with the way you use your class.

Comment: I didn't want to initialize the bounds at the start.  I don't know how many rows/columns I will have.  I knew that I would get some side glances for the not "lists" aspect of the question.  Basically, I'm using ClosedXML to create some Excel files.  It works great, but the performance starts to decline once the row count increases so I was thinking about using my own data structure and then at the very last second, writing out the Excel file.  I want my data structure and the Excel output to "match" [as closely as possible].

Comment: @JasonV If you don't want to initialize the bounds at the start, you can use lists and insert blank spaces where cells are empty. For example if you start with an empty list of lists and set like [2 (row), 3 (column)] = "Test", I'd insert 2 empty lists for rows 0 and 1, and then create a third one for row 2. After that, create 3 empty cells for columns 0, 1 and 2, and then put "Test" in the next cell. That can be done easily through algorithms. Dictionaries can be used too but I feel like hashing is overkill for this and you won't be able to iterate through them as easily.